# Android detect in motion

Tags: android, android-sensors, motion-detection

I have a android tablet which is on a indoor vehicle. I want to use android's sensor to detect if this vehicle is in motion state or not. theoretically it can be in uniform motion tho it's not possible in real. I know how to use accelerometer to detect motion like shaking and walking. But I didn't find any resource talking about how to detect long time motion status. Is it doable using sensors in android like accelerometer, gyro, geomagnetism etc? Please note, since this is only used indoor, I can't use GPS to detect the location. Even if I use some easy to implement indoor location like beacon, it's not accurate enough cus we want to detect accuracy around 1 meter of movement. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at https://developers.google.com/awareness/ and analyse whether it meets your expectation.

Comment: how good is it? does it detect driving state fast? or is it still better to just use GPS and get speed from location to understand if a user is driving? Because Awareness API doesn't use GPS/Location I can't tell if it's accurate

Answer (score 0):

The theory says that it would be possible with the acceleration sensors after being calibrated with the device completely stopped, but I am sure that the accuracy of the sensors of a telephone is totally insufficient to have something reliable.